# Split "Nested" String By Parentheses into Nested List

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a string representation of a tree. I'd like to convert it to a nested list. Is there a way to do this recursively, so that I end up with nested lists?

An example string looks like:

```
(TOP (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP need) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN flight)) (PP
(IN from) (NP (NNP Atlanta))) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (NNP Charlotte)) (NP
(NNP North) (NNP Carolina)))) (NP (JJ next) (NNP Monday))))))
```

So far I've the below, but it does not give me what I'm looking for, at all.

```
import sys
import re

for tree_str in sys.stdin:
    print [", ".join(x.split()) for x in re.split(r'[()]',tree_str) if x.strip()]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want as output? Do the spaces in the string matter?

Comment: That's an interestingly human-readable tree serialization.

Comment: Spaces don't matter. This is from the Penn Treebank, which can, sometimes, be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be something like this:

```
import re


def make_tree(data):
    items = re.findall(r"\(|\)|\w+", data)

    def req(index):
        result = []
        item = items[index]
        while item != ")":
            if item == "(":
                subtree, index = req(index + 1)
                result.append(subtree)
            else:
                result.append(item)
            index += 1
            item = items[index]
        return result, index

    return req(1)[0]


string = "(TOP (S (NP (PRP I))..." # omitted for readability
tree = make_tree(string)

print(tree)
# Output: ['TOP', ['S', ['NP', ['PRP', 'I']]...
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky but kinda does the trick anyway :) You definitely have your nested lists.

```
import re
import ast

input = "(TOP (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP need) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN flight)) (PP (IN from) (NP (NNP Atlanta))) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (NNP Charlotte)) (NP (NNP North) (NNP Carolina)))) (NP (JJ next) (NNP Monday))))))"

# replaces all brackets by square brackets
# and adds commas when needed
input = input.replace("(", "[")\
             .replace(")", "]")\
             .replace("] [", "], [")

# places all the words between double quotes
# and appends a comma after each
input = re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'"\1",', input)

# safely evaluates the resulting string
output = ast.literal_eval(input)

print(output)
print(type(output))

# ['TOP', ['S', ['NP', ['PRP', 'I']], ['VP', ['VBP', 'need'], ['NP', ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'flight']], ['PP', ['IN', 'from'], ['NP', ['NNP', 'Atlanta']]], ['PP', ['TO', 'to'], ['NP', ['NP', ['NNP', 'Charlotte']], ['NP', ['NNP', 'North'], ['NNP', 'Carolina']]]], ['NP', ['JJ', 'next'], ['NNP', 'Monday']]]]]]
# <class 'list'>
```

Note: for safety reasons, `ast.literal_eval()` throws an error if the expression contains operators or some kind of logic, so that you can use it without having to check for malicious code first.

Comment: Beautiful kludge! Normally I'd strongly discourage using `str.replace` and `eval` to do something like this, but in this case it really does seem like the fastest approach.

Comment: Note I would probably dispense with making it a list and just do `input.replace(") (", "), (")`, `re.sub(r"(\w+)", r'"\1",', input)` and `output = ast.literal_eval(input)` but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Writing a simple parser for [S-Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expressions) is not that hard:

```
import pprint
import re

pattern = r'''
    (?P<open_paren> \( ) |
    (?P<close_paren> \) ) |
    (?P<word> \w+) |
    (?P<whitespace> \s+) |
    (?P<eof> $) |
    (?P<error> \S)
'''

scan = re.compile(pattern=pattern, flags=re.VERBOSE).finditer

text = '''
(TOP (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VBP need) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN flight))
 (PP (IN from) (NP (NNP Atlanta))) (PP (TO to) (NP (NP (NNP Charlotte))
 (NP (NNP North) (NNP Carolina)))) (NP (JJ next) (NNP Monday))))))
'''

ERR_MSG = 'input string kaputt!!'

stack = [[]]

for match in scan(text):
    token_type = match.lastgroup
    token = match.group(0)
    if token_type == 'open_paren':
        stack.append([])
    elif token_type == 'close_paren':
        top = stack.pop()
        stack[-1].append(top)
    elif token_type == 'word':
        stack[-1].append(token)
    elif token_type == 'whitespace':
        pass
    elif token_type == 'eof':
        break
    else:
        raise Exception(ERR_MSG)

if 1 == len(stack) == len(stack[0]):
    pprint.pprint(stack[0][0])
else:
    raise Exception(ERR_MSG)
```

Result:

```
['TOP',
 ['S',
  ['NP', ['PRP', 'I']],
  ['VP',
   ['VBP', 'need'],
   ['NP',
    ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'flight']],
    ['PP', ['IN', 'from'], ['NP', ['NNP', 'Atlanta']]],
    ['PP',
     ['TO', 'to'],
     ['NP',
      ['NP', ['NNP', 'Charlotte']],
      ['NP', ['NNP', 'North'], ['NNP', 'Carolina']]]],
    ['NP', ['JJ', 'next'], ['NNP', 'Monday']]]]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is called "parsing".  One parser generator for Python seems to be [Yapps](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/).  Yapps' documentation even [shows](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/yapps2/manual/node2.html#SECTION00022000000000000000) how to write a Lisp parser, of which your application seems to be just a subset.

The subset that you need seems to be:

```
parser Sublisp:
    ignore:      '\\s+'
    token ID:    '[-+*/!@%^&=.a-zA-Z0-9_]+' 

    rule expr:   ID     {{ return ('id', ID) }}
               | list   {{ return list }}
    rule list: "\\("    {{ result = [] }} 
               ( expr   {{ result.append(expr) }}
               )*  
               "\\)"    {{ return result }}
```

After compiling, this will parse your string to a tree of tuples ('id', 'FOO').  To get the tree in the form you desire, you can either modify the generated python code (it is quite readable) or transform the tree afterwards.

Comment: @Adam_G: Yapps is a parser generator, written in Python, that produces Python code from a grammar definition.  The above is such a grammar definition.